# How do I know if I'm on road between two points in android

Tags: android, sdk, navigation, location

I have a list of start point and end point coordinates for zoned roads.  When I put the coordinates in to google maps it shows the road correctly.  I want to develop an android application that will alert me if I am on a zoned road.

How can I check if my current location is in the zone if I have only the start point and end point?  can I use the navigation in some way?

Comment: I dont get what you mean by "zoned roads". Do you just want to see if your current point is between 2 given points ?

Comment: As an example if a road speed limit is reduced due to road works.  I have the start coordinates of the road works and the end coordinates.  The road may not necessarily travel in a straight line so I cannot just  calculate all the points in between.  I need to determine if I am actually on the road that is between the start coordinate and end coordinate.  If I put these coordinates in to google maps it shows the route of the road and not just a straight line from one point to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a point is between two other points, the first solution that crossed my mind is as follows:

Imagine you have a triangle (point of interest, and the two end points ). If the hypotenuse is represented by the two end points, you can get the two angles that it makes with your point of interest. If both of the angles are <= 90 degrees, then the point is between them, if otherwise, it is not.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: the problem is I think that roads do not necessarily travel in a straight line between two points.